# Git: Rename or move all files at once

Tags: git

I want to rename all erb files in my Git project to haml.(like index.html.erb to index.html.haml)

If I rename each file, I have to type the following command more than thirty times.

```
$ git mv app/views/pages/index.html.erb app/views/pages/index.html.haml
```

I tried the command below, but it did not work.

```
$ git mv app/views/**/*.erb app/views/**/*.haml

usage: git mv [options] <source>... <destination>

    -n, --dry-run         dry run
    -f, --force           force move/rename even if target exists
    -k                    skip move/rename errors
```

How can I rename them at once?

Comment: It's the same as ... and other `mv` command. Move the directories one at a time, or write a quich bash loop to do what you're tyring to do right now if you don't want to move all the files.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
for i in $(find . -iname "*.erb"); do
    git mv "$i" "$(echo $i | rev | cut -d '.' -f 2- | rev).haml";
done
```

For each .erb file, `git mv` it to itself with the extension ".erb" replaced by ".haml".

Comment: You need to wrap second argument to `mv` in `"` or it won't work with file names with spaces.

Comment: @Banthar You only noticed because I got it right on my first answer :-P. Anyway, this isn't going to work with filenames containing the quotation mark - the "right" way is to run the names through `printf "%q"` or the like.

Comment: In fact, it doesn't matter, because `for` will split on spaces anyway. I guess the best solution is to not put silly characters in your filenames.

Comment: My git bash in windows does not ship with the rev utility.

Answer (score 9):

A one liner using powershell

```
Dir *.erb -Recurse | foreach { git mv $_.FullName $_.FullName.replace("erb", "haml")}
```

Comment: This works but will also replace all `erb` instances in the whole path, not only extension. What I used instead is this: `Dir *.h -Recurse | foreach { git mv $_.FullName ($_.Directory.FullName + "\" + $_.BaseName + ".hpp") }`.

Comment: Only @Vennor suggestion worked for me

Comment: This did not work for me exactly. I got a bunch of "fatal **** is outside repository" complaints, probably because of the Directory.FullName part. `Dir *.rdb  | foreach { git mv $_.Name ($_.BaseName + ".csv") }` did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me using Powershell:

```
Get-ChildItem -File | foreach { git mv ($_.BaseName+".js") ($_.BaseName+".ts") }
```

For safety I chose not to add -Recurse.

Replace file extensions with whatever you need.

Comment: Very handy, thanks. In my instance, I wanted to move en masse and replace spaces, so amended your code to `Get-ChildItem -File | foreach { git mv ($_.name) ($_.name –replace " ","_") }`

Comment: @Pauk Learned something new with that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Further to @Borealid's answer, it can be simpler:

```sh
for i in $(find . -iname "*.[old-extension]"); do
  git mv "$i" "${i/[old-extension]/[new-extension]}";
done
```

While `[old-extension]` and `[new-extension]` should replaced with real extension.

The slash symbols (`/`) is the [bash syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13210909/863110) of replace in strings.

Answer (score 0):

In windows, you need 2 batch files. 1 we will generate, the other is fixed.

Example below to git rename recursively all *.js into *.ts
Assumption: filename has no empty spaces.

### Step 1: fixed file **git-rn.bat**

```
@echo off
set _srcfile=%1
set _tgtfile=%_srcfile:.js=.ts%
git mv %_srcfile% %_tgtfile%
```

Save it at the same place/directory where **git-rn-all.bat**

### Step 2: generate file **git-rn-all.bat** by using a command

> cd 'C:\projects\some-git-project\src\client\app'
>   dir /a /s /b *.js > git-rn-all.bat

### Step 3: Modify **git-rn-all.bat** for our needs.

Edit **git-rn-all.bat** and text-replace-all the common base path to add a call to the **git-rn.bat**. Any text editor can easily do that.

example:

> C:\projects\some-git-project\src\client\app\app.module.js

becomes

> call git-rn.bat C:\projects\some-git-project\src\client\app\app.module.js

### Step 4: execute **git-rn-all.bat**

you will see quite a big output

### Step 5: remove batch files

remove **git-rn-all.bat** and **git-rn.bat** you probably don't need them any longer.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not the answer to the exact question here, it still matches this question title, so I think it may serve others like me, who got here googling to perform git rename by adding suffix before file extension (it worked for me):

```
for i in *.<file extension>
do
    git mv -v "${i}" "${i%.*}_SUFFIX.${i##*.}"
done
```

- `<file extension>` should be replaced with your required type, E.g. c for C files
- `_SUFFIX` should be replaced with your required suffix before file type
- In case you don't use git and just Linux bash, simply remove `git` from the command