# Replace one substring for another string in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have "I love Suzi and Marry" and I want to change "Suzi" to "Sara".

```
firstString="I love Suzi and Marry"
secondString="Sara"
```

Desired result:

```
firstString="I love Sara and Marry"
```

Comment: For the record, this may have been a fine question once upon a time, but since many years now, Stack Overflow does *not* encourage "give me code" type of questions. Please don't take this as a good example of how to ask questions here.

Comment: @tripleee what exactly is the purpose of Stack Overflow if people aren't allowed to ask for code examples?

Comment: Most questions of this type are too broad, and these days also duplicates. Probably review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre]. Perhaps see also the [Stack Overflow homework FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) which expands on a related topic.

Comment: @tripleee You mean, those questions tend to be too specific, asking only for a special case applied to their specific situation instead of asking for a general class of equal problems. If stack overflow would be able to group related questions in classes, it would improve usability.
It sems, after decades we still need a website that lists for every mental concept or generic operation how to achieve it with any selected programming technology (code examples, patterns or templates exactly). Documentations typically do not provide these mappings and we need to search all over the web.

Answer (score 2283, accepted):

To replace the *first* occurrence of a pattern with a given string, use `${parameter/pattern/string}`:

```
#!/bin/bash
firstString="I love Suzi and Marry"
secondString="Sara"
echo "${firstString/Suzi/"$secondString"}"    
# prints 'I love Sara and Marry'
```

To replace *all* occurrences, use `${parameter//pattern/string}`:

```
message='The secret code is 12345'
echo "${message//[0-9]/X}"           
# prints 'The secret code is XXXXX'
```

(This is documented in [the *Bash Reference Manual*, §3.5.3 "Shell Parameter Expansion"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).)

Note that this feature is not specified by POSIX — it's a Bash extension — so not all Unix shells implement it. For the relevant POSIX documentation, see [*The Open Group Technical Standard Base Specifications, Issue 7*, the *Shell & Utilities* volume, §2.6.2 "Parameter Expansion"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02).

Comment: @ruakh how do I write this statement with a or condition. Just if I want to replace Suzi or Marry with new string.

Comment: @Priyatham51: There's no built-in feature for that. Just replace one, then the other.

Comment: @ruakh : Thank you for your reply . I already did that yesterday, and just wanted to check with you if there is an option so that I don't have to write two lines of code. :)

Comment: Will this work for replacing "\n" (newline) with "<br />" (html break)? `$STRING="${STRING/\n/<br />}"`

Comment: @Bu: No, because `\n` in that context would represent itself, not a newline. I don't have Bash handy right now to test, but you should be able to write something like, `$STRING="${STRING/$'\n'/<br />}"`. (Though you probably want `STRING//` -- replace-all -- instead of just `STRING/`.)

Comment: And if original string contains "/home/user/dir/" and I want to replace "/home/usr" by "/home" (getting the result "/home/dir/") ? how can I escape the meaning of "/" itself?

Comment: @DenioMariz: `foo=/home/user/dir`, followed by `echo "${foo/\/home\/user//home}"`, will print `/home/dir`.

Comment: To be clear, since this confused me for a bit, the first part has to be a variable reference. You can't do `echo ${my string foo/foo/bar}`. You'd need `input="my string foo"; echo ${input/foo/bar}`

Comment: @ruakh Mary is usually spelled with a single r :D

Comment: @JobJob: Who cares how it's "usually" spelled? The OP wrote `Marry`, end of story.

Comment: @ruakh Oh shit - so they did! My apologies, should've commented on the OP. To be clear - was just having a bit of a laugh :D

Comment: @DenioMariz I have `foo = "$(pwd)"` and `bar="/test/"` how can I use now `echo "${foo/bar/profi/}" `

Comment: NB: If the replacement string contains slashes, just escape them. `path=/home/me/docs; echo "${path/me\/docs/you\/docs}"`

Comment: How do I replace X with Y and A with B also. Would it be like `${${I like Suzi and Marry/Suzi/Sara}/like/love}`, `${I like Suzi and Marry/Suzi/Sara/like/love}`, or something else?

Comment: @facepalm42: That was asked and answered in the first two comments to this answer.

Comment: Where are parameters like the global selector `//` explained? And which characters do I need to escape in match and replace ?

Comment: @mgutt: This answer links to the relevant documentation. The documentation is not perfect -- for example, instead of mentioning `//` directly, it mentions what happens "If *pattern* begins with ‘`/`’" (which isn't even accurate, since the rest of that sentence assumes that the extra `/` is not actually part of the pattern) -- but I don't know of any better source.

Comment: Why am I getting error about Bad substitution? I copied the entire code.

Comment: @Čamo: I'm not a psychic, so unless you post details about what you're doing, I won't be able to tell you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: The reason was that I was not in bash. I called it via sh .... and it should be bash ....

Comment: @ruakh I've done multiple tests on Bash 4.4 and you can't do two replacements in a row. It doesn't work seemingly because it executes the second statement before the first one has stored the result in the variable needed in the second replacement. If there is a way to force the first statement to store its result in the variable before the second one executes please tell me.

Comment: @PHPGuru: You must be doing something interestingly different from what I'm picturing; but I can't guess what. Maybe post a question with the details? (If you do post a question, feel free to comment here linking to it. I'm curious. :-) )

Comment: my_array="${my_array[@]//*\/tmp\/*/}"
  my_array="${my_array[@]//*\/cache\/*/}"

Comment: @PHPGuru: OK, I see what you're doing wrong. If you post a question and comment here with a link to it, I'll post an answer (unless someone beats me to it).

Comment: Sure https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62855432/two-shell-parameter-expansions-one-after-the-next-doesnt-work-bash

Comment: Can I make the pattern case-insensitive?

Comment: this solution is giving me bad substitution.
echo "${firstString/Suzi/$secondString}"

Comment: I also get a bad substitution, my command has /, spaces, symbols like %,+

Answer (score 356):

This can be done entirely with [Bash string manipulation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
first="I love Suzy and Mary"
second="Sara"
first=${first/Suzy/$second}
```

That will replace only the first occurrence; to replace them all, double the first slash:

```
first="Suzy, Suzy, Suzy"
second="Sara"
first=${first//Suzy/$second}
# first is now "Sara, Sara, Sara"
```

Comment: It appears that they both answered in the exact same minute :O

Comment: What if `first` or `second` contain special characters, like `/`, `$`, `{`, `}`, <backslash>, `.`, `+`, `(`, `)`, `*`, etc.? (Problems with formatting of backslash in this comment.) Perhaps address that in the answer?

Comment: As to wildcards this worked for me `r_getfilter="${r_getfilter/../.*}"`  to replace `..` with `.*` (a grep "match anything" string).  Using `'.*'` did **not** go well, the single quotes ended up in the substitution.

Answer (score 229):

For Dash all previous posts aren't working

The POSIX `sh` compatible solution is:

```
result=$(echo "$firstString" | sed "s/Suzi/$secondString/")
```

This will replace the first occurrence on each line of input. Add a `/g` flag to replace all occurrences:

```
result=$(echo "$firstString" | sed "s/Suzi/$secondString/g")
```

Comment: I got this:
_$ echo $(echo $firstString | sed 's/Suzi/$secondString/g')_
**I love $secondString and Marry**

Comment: @Qstnr_La use double quotes for variable substitution: `result=$(echo $firstString | sed "s/Suzi/$secondString/g")`

Comment: Plus 1 for showing how to output to a variable as well. Thanks!

Comment: I fixed the single quotes and also added the missing quotes around the `echo` argument. It deceptively works without quoting with simple strings, but easily breaks on any nontrivial input string (irregular spacing, shell metacharacters, etc).

Comment: In sh (AWS Codebuild / Ubuntu sh) I found that I need a single slash at the end, not a double. I'm going to edit the comment as the comments above also show a single slash.

Comment: One should keep in mind that search string (in this case `Suzi`) is a regular expression, so some characters have special meaning (try matching a dot `.`)

Answer (score 93):

Try this:

```
sed "s/Suzi/$secondString/g" <<< "$firstString"
```

The three greater-than signs create a [here string](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80362/what-does-mean).

Comment: You don't actually need Sed for this; Bash supports this sort of replacement natively.

Comment: I guess this is tagged "bash" but came here because needed something simple for another shell. This is a nice succinct alternative to what https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh#A.24.7Bparm.2BAC8.3F.2BAC8-pat.5B.2BAC8-str.5D.7D made it look like I'd need.

Comment: This works great for ash/dash or any other POSIX sh.

Comment: I get error **sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unknown option to \`s**

Comment: @ruakh Actually, I found this useful for cases where the haystack string is big. With the other option I was getting `zsh: command too long`.

Comment: First answer that works with stdin, great for pipelining strings.

Comment: @ruakh this answer works with **pipes**. Like `my_command | sed ... | ...`

Comment: @NamGVU, or anyone else getting that error, it usually means that one of the strings in your search or replace section has the same character as your delimiters. For example, it's common to use / as a delimiter, but if your strings contain *nix directories, then you'll see that error since they also have the / character.

Comment: @YoshuaWuyts The `<<<` "here string" syntax is not POSIX.

Answer (score 70):

It's better to use Bash than `sed` if strings have regular expression characters.

```
echo ${first_string/Suzi/$second_string}
```

It's portable to Windows and works with at least as old as Bash 3.1.

To show you don't need to worry much about escaping, let's turn this:

```
/home/name/foo/bar
```

Into this:

```
~/foo/bar
```

But only if `/home/name` is in the beginning. We don't need `sed`!

Given that Bash gives us magic variables `$PWD` and `$HOME`, we can:

```
echo "${PWD/#$HOME/\~}"
```

---

Thanks for Mark Haferkamp in the comments for the note on quoting/escaping `~`.*

Note how the variable `$HOME` contains slashes, but this didn't break anything.

Further reading: [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html#SUBSTRREPL00). 
If using `sed` is a must, be sure to [escape every character](http://backreference.org/2009/12/09/using-shell-variables-in-sed/).

Comment: This answer stopped me from using `sed` with the `pwd` command to avoid defining a new variable each time my custom `$PS1` runs. Does Bash provide a more general way than magic variables to use the output of a command for string replacement? As for your code, I had to escape the `~` to keep Bash from expanding it into $HOME. Also, what does the `#` in your command do?

Comment: @MarkHaferkamp [See this](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html#SUBSTRREPL02) from the "further reading recommended" link. About "escaping the `~`": notice how I quoted stuff. Remember to always quote stuff! And this doesn't just work for magic variables: any variable is capable of substitutions, getting string length, and more, within bash. Congrats on trying to your `$PS1` fast: you may also be interested in [`$PROMPT_COMMAND`](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x264.html) if you are more comfortable in another programming language and want to code a compiled prompt.

Comment: The "further reading" link explains the "#". On Bash 4.3.30, `echo "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"` doesn't replace my `$HOME` with `~`. Replacing `~` with `\~` or `'~'` works. Any of these work on Bash 4.2.53 on another distro. Can you please update your post to quote or escape the `~` for better compatibility? What I meant by my "magic variables" question was: Can I use Bash's variable substitution on, e.g., the output of `uname` without saving it as a variable first? As for my personal `$PROMPT_COMMAND`, [it's complicated](https://github.com/refola/scripts/blob/master/sourced/prompt).

Comment: @MarkHaferkamp Whoa, you're totally right, my bad. Will update the answer now.

Comment: It seems that I was wrong.... Actually rebooting between Chakra Linux and openSUSE (as opposed to chrooting) shows that `${PWD/#$HOME/~}` works in Bash 4.2.53 on SUSE and `${PWD/#$HOME/\~}` works in Bash 4.3.30 on Chakra, but not vice versa. A workaround that works on both distros is to replace `~` with `$(echo '~')`, as in the verbose `${PWD/#$HOME/$(echo '~')}`. **Edit**: I just realized that `$'~'` might be better. I'm testing it now.

Comment: Please ignore the edit in my previous comment. `$'~'` works great in an echo command, but caused me nothing but frustration when I tried to use it in $PS1 to get a literal `~`. `$(echo '~')` seems to be the best workaround.

Comment: @MarkHaferkamp Bash and its obscure pitfalls... :P

Comment: this will break if, for example, your name was "abc" and you were in /home/abcd.
should search for `$HOME/` but you'll have to escape the slash

Answer (score 39):

```
echo [string] | sed "s|[original]|[target]|g"
```

- "s" means "substitute"
- "g" means "global, all matching occurrences"

Comment: The `g` flag is hugely misunderstood. Without it, `sed` will replace the first occurrence *on each line* but if you don't expect multiple occurrences per line, you don't need `g`. (Frequently you see it in expressions where there could only ever be a single match per line, like `s/.*everything.*/all of it/g` where obviously you are matching the entire line in the first place, so there is no way you could match the regex several times).

Comment: this works perfectly when replacing paths with "/"

Answer (score 33):

If tomorrow you decide you don't love Marry either she can be replaced as well:

```
today=$(</tmp/lovers.txt)
tomorrow="${today//Suzi/Sara}"
echo "${tomorrow//Marry/Jesica}" > /tmp/lovers.txt
```

There must be [50 ways to leave your lover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/50_Ways_to_Leave_Your_Lover).

Answer (score 21):

Since I can't add a comment.  @ruaka To make the example more readable write it like this

```
full_string="I love Suzy and Mary"
search_string="Suzy"
replace_string="Sara"
my_string=${full_string/$search_string/$replace_string}
or
my_string=${full_string/Suzy/Sarah}
```

Comment: Till I came to your example I had understood the order the other way round. This helped clarify what is happening

Comment: the replacement order much clear to understand, thanks

Answer (score 13):

Using [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK):

```
firstString="I love Suzi and Marry"
echo "$firstString" | awk '{gsub("Suzi","Sara"); print}'
```

Comment: That trick is the way to go if what you're trying to split isn't actually in a variable but in a text file. Thanks, @Payam!

Answer (score 12):

Pure *POSIX* shell method, which unlike [*Roman Kazanovskyi*'s `sed`-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22957485/6136214) needs no external tools, just the shell's own native [parameter expansions](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.osdevice/korn_shell_parmsub1.htm).  Note that long file names are minimized so the code fits better on one line:

```
f="I love Suzi and Marry"
s=Sara
t=Suzi
[ "${f%$t*}" != "$f" ] && f="${f%$t*}$s${f#*$t}"
echo "$f"
```

Output:

```
I love Sara and Marry
```

---

How it works:

- Remove Smallest Suffix Pattern.  `"${f%$t*}"` returns "*`I love`*" if the suffix `$t` "*`Suzi*`*" is in `$f` "*`I love`* ***`Suzi and Marry`***".
- But if `t=Zelda`, then `"${f%$t*}"` deletes nothing, and returns the whole string "*`I love Suzi and Marry`*".
- This is used to test if `$t` is in `$f` with `[ "${f%$t*}" != "$f" ]` which will evaluate to *true* if the `$f` string contains "*`Suzi*`*" and *false* if not.
- If the test returns *true*, construct the desired string using *Remove Smallest Suffix Pattern* `${f%$t*}` "*`I love`*" and *Remove Smallest Prefix Pattern* `${f#*$t}` "*`and Marry`*", with the *2nd* string `$s` "*`Sara`*" in between.

Comment: it's worth noting that this depends on t occurring only once in f but it can be modified with a loop and one longest match to replace multiple occurrences

Comment: The only thing I'd add after all this time is to better quote the variables to protect their expanded values.

`[ "${f%"$t"*}" != "$f" ] && f="${f%"$t"*}$s${f#*"$t"}"]`

Answer (score 8):

Pattern to substitute the first occurrence with special charters:

> ${parameter/pattern/string}

Pattern to substitute all occurrence with special charters:

> ${parameter//pattern/string}

```
firstString="I love //Suzi// and Marry"
secondString="Sara"
firstString="${firstString/\/\/Suzi\/\//"$secondString"}"
echo $firstString
```

It will print: `I love Sara and Marry`

Answer (score 8):

I think this is the cleanest form for your use case:

```
firstString="${firstString//Suzi/$secondString}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ls *.ext | awk '{print "mv "$1" "$1".newext"}' | sed "s/.ext.newext/.newext/" | parallel {}
```

Answer (score 0):

based on proposed above awk solution, I would extend it to use awk-variables.
This will allow passing a text containing special chars..

```
aString="I love _p1_ very much!"
aVar="complicated \" text \' with \. special ) chars"
awk -v p1="$aVar" '{gsub("_p1_",p1); print}' <<< $aString
```

produces:

```
I love complicated " text ' with . special ) chars very much
```

it would be uneasy to implement this case with `sed -e` or `bash` substitutions.

Answer (score 0):

As python now builtin available in linux, I would suggest this py string replace `str.replace()`

```
firstString="I love Suzi and Marry"
secondString="Sara"

secondString=`python3 -c "s='$firstString'.replace('Suzi', 'Sara'); print(s)" `
echo $secondString
```

Answer (score -1):

The only way I found is store the string in a file, use sed then store the file content in a var :

```
echo "I love Suzy" > tmp.txt
sed -i "s/Suzy/Sarah/" tmp.txt
set res=`cat tmp.txt`
echo $res
rm tmp.txt
```

I don't know which kind of shell I am using (only thing I found is sh-4.2 if I type 'sh') but all classic syntax fails, like the simple `test=${test2}`.
It fails 2 times : at the assignment (must use `set`) and at the `${}`.

Comment: Sounds like you are using `csh`, but even that supported pipes. `sh-4.2` looks like Bash running in POSIX compatibility mode, but that would not require (or understand) the `set` syntax. There was a time when Csh was quite popular in spite of its obvious flaws, but that was 30+ years ago; probably join us in abandoning it.

Answer (score -1):

Using `sed` we can do it easily

```
sed -i "s+$value_to_be_replaced+$with_variable1 "some character" $with_variable2+g" $file_name
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but the broken nested quoting and the lack of explanation (as well as the inadequate formatting, but I fixed that) are all problematic.