# Where is the php.ini file on a Linux/CentOS PC?

Tags: php, linux, centos

I can't find PHP.ini location on my server. I've checked all Stack Overflow answers but I can't find my php.ini location.

I have Linux, Cent OS, zPanel. Last version of PHP.

My computer: Linux Mint 15 KDE.

Answer (score 341, accepted):

In your terminal/console (only Linux, in windows you need [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html))

```
ssh user@ip
php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"
```

And it will show you something like this `Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini`.

**ALTERNATIVE METHOD**

You can make a php file on your website, which run: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`, and you can see the php.ini location on the line with: *"Loaded Configuration File"*.

**Update**
This command gives the path right away

```
cli_php_ini=php -i | grep /.+/php.ini -oE  #ref. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15763333/248616
    php_ini="${cli_php_ini/cli/apache2}"   #replace cli by apache2 ref. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13210909/248616
```

Comment: This is not the php.ini for all things. Its for the CLI. 

on ubuntu 16.04 / php7.0 (default); this is going to give you 

/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini (or similar)

for apache it will be at 

/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini


Php info will only give you the highest level of php.ini; so if you drop info in an html dir, it will show THAT one (not default apache, etc)

Please update answer, its near complete ;)

Comment: `php -i | grep "php.ini"` is more easy to remember. ;)

Comment: `php -i | grep php.ini` is even easier

Comment: note that `php -i` tells the php.ini for CLI **not** the apache's one

Comment: `php -i | grep /.+/php.ini -oE` gives exact the path [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15763333/248616)

Comment: php --ini is doing the same thing right?

Comment: Worked perfect for me.

Comment: I got `php: command not found`, I have the Apache module but not the cli. `phpinfo()` works well

Answer (score 35):

On most installs you can find it here:

```
/etc/php.ini
```

Comment: How can you change the loaded configuration file from /usr/local/lib/php.ini to /etc/php.ini ?

Comment: @user689017 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200498/change-php-ini-location-file

Answer (score 33):

You can find the path to `php.ini` in the output of `phpinfo()`. See under "Loaded Configuration File".

[image]

Comment: thank you, but i used ITChristian ssh command, thank you

Comment: No problem, just two different ways of doing it. Might be helpful to others later.

Answer (score 13):

```
php -i |grep 'Configuration File'
```

Comment: This is my preferred method because you don't have to search the file to see it.

Answer (score 7):

`#php -i | grep php.ini` also will work too!