# Change PHP.ini location file?

Tags: php, apache2, filemaker

I'm using apache2 on OSX, by default the `php.ini` location is:

```
/private/etc/php.ini
```

I need to change it to this...

```
/Library/FileMaker Server/Web Publishing/publishing-engine/php/lion/lib/php.ini
```

Any help?

Answer (score 7):

Use **PHPIniDir** directive in apache config file after LoadModule :

> **example**:
>
> LoadModule php5_module /path/to/php5_module
>
> PHPIniDir path/to/php.ini

Or set the **PHPRC** environment variable:

> **example**:
>
> export PHPRC=path/to/php.ini

Comment: Ok I did that, it shows me in the phpinfo test I ran that the destination is corrent.

But if I run PHP --ini it shows me this:

Loaded Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File: /private/etc/php.ini

That looks like where I need to replace it but I can't find the file

Comment: add method for cli mode

Comment: /private/etc/ is the same as /etc/ on the mac.  instead of changing the php.ini file, which does not exist by default (you are supposed to copy php.ini.default to php.ini), you could use the filemaker server deployment wizard which just modifies /etc/httpd/httpd.conf similar to the suggested answer.  http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/6538/~/installing-php-via-filemaker-server-deployment-wizard

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows and using XAMPP, you can probably edit the file: **xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf**, and change the php.ini location as below:

```
<IfModule php5_module>
     PHPINIDir "/xampp/php-5.6.5"
</IfModule>
```