# How to replace one character with two characters using tr

Tags: shell, unix, tr

Can tr replace one character with two characters?

I am trying to replace "~" with "~\n" but the output does not produce the newline.

```
$ echo "asdlksad ~ adlkajsd ~ 12345" | tr "~" "~\n"
asdlksad ~ adlkajsd ~ 12345
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

No, `tr` is specifically intended to replace single characters by single characters (or, depending on command-line options, to delete characters or replace runs of a single character by one occurrence.).

`sed` is probably the best tool for this particular job:

```
$ echo "asdlksad ~ adlkajsd ~ 12345" | sed 's/~/~\n/g'
asdlksad ~
 adlkajsd ~
 12345
```

(Note that this requires `sed` to interpret the backlash-n `\n` sequence as a newline character. GNU sed does this, but [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) doesn't specify it except within a regular expression, and there are definitely older versions of `sed` that don't.)

Answer (score 7):

you could go with awk, let FS/OFS variable do the job for you:

```
awk -F'~' -v OFS="~\n" '$1=$1'
```

test with your example:

```
kent$ awk -F'~' -v OFS="~\n" '$1=$1' <<< "asdlksad ~ adlkajsd ~ 12345" 
asdlksad ~
 adlkajsd ~
 12345
```

Comment: This solved a problem for me, but it was not clear to me what was happening, so I dug a little deeper for some clarity:  "-F" == "input field separator" and "-OFS" == "output field separator" (the trick here being that the "OFS" can be multi-character) and the "<<<" passes the quoted string to awk as STDIN (in the same shell) - this avoids the issue with pipes where the transaction is done in a different sub-shell.

Answer (score 7):

`tr` can only do 1 to 1 translation.

Here is one way of doing that **using pure Bash:**

```
s='"asdlksad ~ adlkajsd ~ 12345'
r=$'~\n'
echo -e "${s//\~/$r}"
asdlksad ~
 adlkajsd ~
 12345
```

Comment: This is probably more efficient than calling utilities like awk or sed.

Comment: See nice explanation of the syntax here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13210909/414125

Answer (score 2):

no can do, sorry.

`tr` is meant to transliterate one character with another.

there are numerous options, but I would use `awk`, i.e.

```
echo "asdlksad ~ adlkajsd ~ 12345" | awk '{gsub(/[~]/, "&\n")};1'
```

**output**

```
asdlksad ~
 adlkajsd ~
 12345
```

Comment: Instead of `/[~]/`, the shorter form `/~/` also works. The `;1` at the end is not necessary. (Or is it, for some obscure old operating system?)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "asdlksad ~ adlkajsd ~ 12345" | sed 's/~/~|/g' | tr '|' '\n'
```

--This will work perfect, since sed having a problem replacing \n

Comment: It doesn't work if the input contains `|` elsewhere.