# Replace hyphens with underscores in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

Trying to write a bash script and in one part of it I need to take whatever parameter was passed to it and replace the hyphens with underscores if they exist.

Tried to do the following

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
string=$1
string=${string//-/_}
echo $string;
```

It's telling me that this line `string=${string//-/_}` fails due to "Bad substitution" but it looks like it should do it? Am I missing something?

Comment: What version of Bash? There's nothing wrong with what you posted.

Comment: What's exact error message? It looks more like you ran the script with something like `sh testScript`, and `sh` isn't actually `bash`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing some characters in a string with another character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2871181/608639), [How to replacw one character with two characters using tr](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18365482/608639), [Replace a space with a period in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5928156/608639), etc.

Comment: @jww except if you actually read what I tried and read those posts, you'd see that I tried that and it didn't work for me using hyphens and underscores. Worked for every other character.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your script, and it should work in modern versions of Bash.

But just in case you can simplify that to :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "$1" | tr '-' '_'
```

This is in case that parameter substitution does not work ( which seems to be your case ).

Regards!