# Replace new line with ||

Tags: bash, ubuntu, replace, command-line

I have a file with several thousand lines. I'm looking to replace newline character with `||` (that is `<space>||<space>`)

I'm wanting to this via bash on Ubuntu 20.04

I've tried the following but in vain -

```
tr '\n' ' || ' < input.txt
tr '\n' ' \|| ' < input.txt
tr '\n' ' \|\| ' < input.txt
```

I'm not able to work out what I'm doing wrong. Please can someone help me spot my mistake?

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: See: [How to replace one character with two characters using tr](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18365482/3776858)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace one character with two characters using tr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365482/how-to-replace-one-character-with-two-characters-using-tr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, just after posting this question, I worked this out. Leaving the answer here if someone someday finds it helpful

```
perl -p -e 's/\n/ || / ' input.txt
```

Comment: Or with GNU sed: `sed -z 's/\n/ || /g' input.txt`

Comment: Or `awk 1 ORS='||' input.txt`

Comment: The only problem with all these solution is that you'll most probably get an `||` at the end of the file; it may be want you want though

Comment: @Fravadona: This could be addressed in this way with GNU sed: `sed -z 's/\n/ || /g; s/ || $/\n/' input.txt`

Comment: Thank you everyone for the wonderful alternates.