# BASH: replace string like in javascript

Tags: bash, shell

I have a variable in a Bash script, and I want to replace all occurrences of `/` in it with `_` and all occurrences of `+` with `-`; and I want to remove all occurrences of `=`. So, if this were JavaScript, something like this:

```
str = str.replace(/\//g, "_").replace(/\+/g, "-").replace(/=/g, "");
```

How can I do this in Bash.

Comment: this is a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210880/replace-one-substring-for-another-string-in-shell-script

Comment: @Hitmands Not strictly a dupe, as this question is about character translation (`tr` territory) whereas the proposed dupe is about longer strings (`sed` territory, though certainly the `y%/+/_-/` command of `sed` could come in handy here as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in BASH:

```
s='my/String+One=Two'
s="${s//\//_}"
s="${s//+/-}"
s="${s//=/}"
echo "$s"
my_String-OneTwo
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "$string" | tr '/+''_-' | tr -d '='
```