# Search in big file that's one big line, and too big to be opened by an editor

Tags: xml, search, grep

I have a big xml file where the whole file is just one line. This is very impractical since I need to search for certain occurrences in the file, which the `grep` command can't help with in this case. I tried to open the file in several editors like notpad++ and sublime, but the file is too big. Is there any clever way to search for occurrences of a string or pattern in linux or windows? The problem with `grep` is of course that it returns the line that the match occurs on, which is no good in this case.

The size of the file is 4GB.

Comment: Yes, there is a very simple way to do it and it does NOT involve editing the existing file to introduce linebreaks! If you post a [mcve] with sample input and expected output then we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can edit the file, or at least edit a copy of the file, I suggest that you split it up into separate lines and then use grep or Notepad++ etc. to search.

Try changing `><` to `>\n<` - this will put each XML element on its own line.

If you need help with the substitution, there's an [SO question on doing string substitution in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210880/replace-one-substring-for-another-string-in-shell-script)

Comment: Thank you, I think I'll just do this to make it easier.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use `grep` you can use `--color=always` for highlighting the part where the match is found

```
grep --color=always Issues.txt
```

[image]

Alternatively, try using `vim` editor for such files.

Also, if you really want to format the xml i.e split it in multiple lines and with indentation you can use `xmllint`

`xmllint --format theXMLFile` which will output to stdout which you can redirect to another file.

If you search a bit you maybe also figure out how to use this from within your favorite editor ( In Kate, I use the command option )

Comment: I didn't know that this was possible actually, but since the file is 4GB this won't really help as much as I want. Still, thank you for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

Most XML editors can cope with this. It's well worth investing in an IDE such as oXygen or Stylus Studio, but there are probably free XML editors that do a good job too. An XML editor will generally allow you to open a single-line XML file and display it nicely indented on multiple lines, taking account of its knowledge of the XML syntax.

Unfortunately you don't say what you mean by "big". It could be 1Mb, 1Gb, or 1Tb - there's a big difference between those numbers! All editors are going to struggle above 50Mb or so.

Answer (score 0):

When I need to open a big file I use less. It is really fast:

```
 less -n filename
```

-n disables line numbers (they take a while to calculate and you do not need them)

You can search with /pattern