# Extract last digits from each word in a string with multiple words using bash

Tags: string, bash, shell, substring, sh

Given a string with multiple words like below, all in one line:

```
first-second-third-201805241346 first-second-third-201805241348 first-second-third-201805241548 first-second-third-201705241540
```

I am trying to the maximum number from the string, in this case the answer should be `201805241548`

I have tried using awk and grep, but I am only getting the answer as last word in the string.

I am interested in how to get this accomplished.

Comment: Show us those efforts. Add it to the question to help you out on that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo 'first-second-third-201805241346 first-second-third-201805241348 first-second-third-201805241548 first-second-third-201705241540' |\
 grep -o '[0-9]\+' | sort -n | tail -1
```

The relevant part is `grep -o '[0-9]\+' | sort -n | tail -n 1`.

Answer (score 2):

Using single `gnu awk` command:

```
s='first-second-third-201805241346 first-second-third-201805241348 first-second-third-201805241548 first-second-third-201705241540'
awk -F- -v RS='[[:blank:]]+' '$NF>max{max=$NF} END{print max}' <<< "$s"
```

```
201805241548
```

Or using `grep + awk` (if `gnu awk` is not available):

```
grep -Eo '[0-9]+' <<< "$s" | awk '$1>max{max=$1} END{print max}'
```

Comment: Why you say gnu awk  ?

Answer (score 1):

Another awk

```
echo 'first-...-201705241540' | awk -v RS='[^0-9]+' '$0>max{max=$0} END{print max}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Gnarly pure `bash`:

```
n='first-second-third-201805241346 \
   first-second-third-201805241348 \
   first-second-third-201805241548 \
   first-second-third-201705241540'
z="${n//+([a-z-])/;p=}"
p=0 m=0 eval echo -n "${z//\;/\;m=\$((m>p?m:p))\;};m=\$((m>p?m:p))"
echo $m
```

Output:

```
201805241548
```

How it works:  This code constructs code, then runs it.

1. `z="${n//+([a-z-])/;p=}"` [substitutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210880/replace-one-substring-for-another-string-in-shell-script) non-numbers with some pre-code
   -- setting `$p` to the value of each number, (useless on its own).  At this point `echo $z` would output:

   ```
   ;p=201805241346 \ ;p=201805241348 \ ;p=201805241548 \ ;p=201705241540
   ```
2. Substitute the added `;`s for *more* code that sets `$m` to the
   greatest value of `$p`, which needs `eval` to run it -- the actual
   code the whole line with `eval` runs looks like this:

   ```
   p=0 m=0
   m=$((m>p?m:p));p=201805241346
   m=$((m>p?m:p));p=201805241348
   m=$((m>p?m:p));p=201805241548
   m=$((m>p?m:p));p=201705241540
   m=$((m>p?m:p))
   ```
3. Print `$m`.

Comment: Maybe there's a non-`eval` way.