# Bash replace string

Tags: bash

I'm working on a script which checks if file exists. If it exists then I want to get the route.

What I did is the following:

```
RESULT_=$(find $PWD -name someRandom.json)
```

This returns the path to the file:

```
/Users/guest/workspace/random_repo/random/some_folder/someRandom.json
```

I'm stuck in the way to navigate among files. Is there a way of replacing `someRandom.json` with `''` so I can do:

```
cd /Users/guest/workspace/random_repo/random/some_folder/
```

I tried using the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210880/replace-one-substring-for-another-string-in-shell-script) but it isn't working. I tried the following:

```
RESULT=$($RESULT/someRandom.json/'')
echo $RESULT
```

And this returns no such file or directory.

Comment: Every character counts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

given:

```
$ echo "$result"
/Users/guest/workspace/random_repo/random/some_folder/someRandom.json
```

You can get the file name:

```
$ basename "$result"
someRandom.json
```

Or the path:

```
$ dirname "$result"
/Users/guest/workspace/random_repo/random/some_folder
```

Or you can use substring deletion:

```
$ echo "${result%/*}"
/Users/guest/workspace/random_repo/random/some_folder
```

Or, given the file name and the full path, just remove the file name:

```
$ echo "$tgt"
someRandom.json
$ echo "${result%"$tgt"}"
/Users/guest/workspace/random_repo/random/some_folder/
```

There are many examples of Bash string manipulation:

[BashFAQ/100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100)

[BashFAQ/073](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073)

[Bash Hacker's Parameter Expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe)

Side note: Avoid using CAPITAL_NAMES for Bash variables. They are reserved for Bash use by convention...

Answer (score 2):

You want parameter expansion, not command substitution.

```
RESULT="${RESULT%/*}/"
```

Comment: You can just use `exec` in the find command.
'find $PWD -name someRandom.json -exec dirname {} \;'

And to cd to it:
`cd $(find $PWD -name someRandom.json -exec dirname {} \;)`

Comment: @Jebby, that's going to behave badly if the directory names have spaces. `"$PWD"` should be quoted, `-quit` should be added at the very end of the `find` command (so it can't return more than one directory), and the command substitution as a whole should have quotes around it.