# Why Parameter Expansion is not working?

Tags: sh, dash-shell, parameter-expansion

I am writing a script and in between. I am trying to replace all the commas of the string stored in a variable to spaces.
basically the variable `dpoint` contains comma saparated floating point numbers
like `0.0,4.2,3.6666`

i am using `dpoint=${dpoint//,/ }` to replace all commas.

here is the exact error what i am getting.

i read this question
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210880/replace-one-substring-for-another-string-in-shell-script).
and i found myself doing nothing wrong..(definitely i am doing... can't figure it out).

[image: screenshot of the problem]

it has been an hour fixing this error.
finally i posted it here what the heck am i doing wrong?

update:
i am using dash shell

Comment: (1) Don't post code as screenshot.

Comment: (2) Please post a [mcve]. The surrounding code may cause the bug.

Comment: Which shell are you using to execute the script? What’s its shebang? How do you run it? `${…/…/…}` is a Bash thing. An other way to do it is `dpoint="$(printf '%s' "${dpoint}" | tr ',' ' ')"`.

Comment: @Biffen Note that [tag:dash] tag ...

Comment: @user202729 I’m also noting the `sh` tag and the Bashism, so I’m guessing there’s some confusion.

Comment: using is /bin/sh pointing to dash

Comment: @sanjeev Then wherever you found the `${…/…/…}` notation was for Bash, and won’t work.

Comment: @user202729 after visiting the link you provided i think dash does not support this type of Parameter expansion.

Comment: `dash` absolutely does not support the `/` operator.

Comment: Oh stack overflow... so you blocked me from posting new questions... after this one................ I need to wait for 6 months in order to post new one... as i am unable to find ( sorry fix .) this post. i don't know what to fix... in it.... neither i can delete the post as this is going to count against me... as said here... https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th

Comment: May be I am not contributing well by asking great questions... but... 6 month is still too much for a new question...