# Creating an alias for xpath expression in xidel with regex and bash

Tags: regex, bash, macos, xpath, xidel

If you have already used Xidel, you will often need to locate nodes that have a certain class. To do this more easy, I want to create `has-class("class")` function that serves as an alias for the expression:
 `contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " class ")`.

Example:

```
$ e-xidel.sh example.com '//article/p//img[has-class("wp-image")]'
```

e-xidel.sh contains this code:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "$(tput setaf 2) Checking... $(tput sgr0)"

path=$1
expression=$2

# expression = '//article/p//img[has-class("wp-image")]'
# Regex to replace every * has-class("class") * by * contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " class ") *
# ...
# ...
# expression = '//article/p//img[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " wp-image ")]'

xoutput=$(xidel $path --printed-node-format=html --output-declaration= -e "$expression")

echo -e "$(tput setaf 1) $xoutput $(tput sgr0)"
```

Comment: Do you absolutely need regex replace? Would a [simple string replace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13210909/1578604) not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **`sed`** (GNU version, cannot guarantee it will work with others implementations) to achieve your need:

```
sed 's/has-class("\([^)]\+\)")/contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " \1 ")/g'
```

**Explanation:**

- **`s/pattern/substitution/g`**: replace the portion matching the pattern by the `substitution` string; g flag for replace all the portions of line (global substitution)
- **`has-class("\([^)]\+\)")`**: a portion starting with `has-class("` containing any character except the closing parenthesis (`[^)]`) and ending by `")`. Escaped parentheses surrounding the inner part capture the subportion and associate it with the alias `\1`, since it's the first created capture group.
- **`contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " \1 ")`**: replace the mached portion by this text; `\1` will be expanded by the content of the associated captured group.

Your script would be:

```
#!/bin/bash

function expand-has-class() {
    echo "$1" |
    sed 's/has-class("\([^)]\+\)")/contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " \1 ")/g'
}

echo -e "$(tput setaf 2) Checking... $(tput sgr0)"

path=$1
expression="$(expand-has-class "$2")"

# expression = '//article/p//img[has-class("wp-image")]'
# Regex to replace every * has-class("class") * by * contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " class ") *
# ...
# ...
# expression = '//article/p//img[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " wp-image ")]'

xoutput=$(xidel $path --printed-node-format=html --output-declaration= -e "$expression")

echo -e "$(tput setaf 1) $xoutput $(tput sgr0)"
```

Comment: I have installed `brew install gnu-sed` and used gsed instead of sed in macOS.

Answer (score 1):

> `contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " class ")`
>
> Example:
>
> `$ e-xidel.sh example.com '//article/p//img[has-class("wp-image")]'`

This makes no sense.

```
contains(concat(" ",normalize-space("wp-image")," ")," wp-image ")
```

would just be the same as

```
contains("wp-image","wp-image")
```

If you really want a boolean as output while comparing the value of the `class` attribute to a literal string then this...

```
xidel -s example.com -e '//article/p//img/@class="wp-image"'
```

...would return `true` or `false`.

If `wp-image` is a substring of the `class` attribute's value:

```
xidel -s example.com -e '//article/p//img/contains(@class,"wp-image")'
```