# how to rename files and thank you

Tags: linux, bash

how I can rename several files (Q0138-9061933666_S5.fasta.db) in a folder and leave only the no as ca (Q0138-9061933666_S5.db) i.e. delete .fasta from all files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are in the folder where the files are placed.

```
for i in *.fasta.db
do
    mv $i ${i/\.fasta/} # remove "fasta" from file name
done
```

See [Replace one substring for another string in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210880/replace-one-substring-for-another-string-in-shell-script) for details about string substitution

Comment: Thank you very much, I have another question, how can I replace the character (-) by (_) for all the files and thank you in advance.

Comment: add a second string substitution in the loop ```mv $newfile ${newfile/-/_}```