# How to trim a string in shell script

Tags: shell

I have a string,

```
var=refs/heads/testing/branch
```

I want to get rid of `refs/heads/` in the string using shell script, such that I have only:

```
var=testing/branch
```

Commands I tried (one per line):

```sh
echo $(var) | awk -F\\ {'print $2'} 
echo $var | sed -e s,refs/heads/,, 
echo "refs/heads/testing/branch" | grep -oP '(?<=refs/heads/\)\w+' 
echo "refs/heads/testing/branch" | LC_ALL=C sed -e 's/.*\\//' 
echo "refs/heads/testing/branch" | cut -d'\' -f2 
echo refs/heads/testing/branch | sed -e s,refs/heads/,,
```

Comment: What have you tried/tested/searched/experimented and that had failed, where ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210880/replace-one-substring-for-another-string-in-shell-script

Comment: @GillesQuenot I tried 1) echo $(var) | awk -F\\ {'print $2'}  2) echo $temp_branch | sed -e s,refs/heads/,, 3) echo "varrandomcollege-nt\user90" | grep -oP '(?<=randomcollege-nt\\)\w+'
echo "randomcollege-nt\user90" | LC_ALL=C sed -e 's/.*\\//'
echo "randomcollege-nt\user90" | cut -d'\' -f2
echo randomcollege-nt\user90| sed -e s,randomcollege-nt\,,

Comment: Add this to your original post

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and add sample input and expected output. For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: How did you get `refs/heads/testing/branch` in the first place? There's probably a better way to get the desired branch name.

Comment: @chepner i get this as part of Azure devops pipeline variable $(System.PullRequest.SourceBranch)

Answer (score 0):

there are lots of options out there ,try easy ones:

```
echo $var | cut -d "/"  -f 3,4
echo $var | awk -F"/" '{print $3"/"$4}'
```

Comment: what is `echo $var` gives you?

Comment: did you define var before running these commands? This is what I did `var="refs/heads/testing/branch"` and then run either of the commands provided you as answers. would be better if you can show the output of `echo $var`

Answer (score 0):

Shell parameter expansion: remove the *prefix* "refs/heads/" from the variable contents

```sh
$ var=refs/heads/testing/branch
$ echo "${var#refs/heads/}"
testing/branch
```

Comment: export: `testing/branch': not a valid identifier as I am running as  export temp_branch=echo "${temp_branch#refs/heads/}"