# Two Shell Parameter Expansions one after the next doesn't work (Bash)

Tags: bash

Using Bash 4.4 I'm trying to get a list of the files from the current directory, put them into an array, and then use shell parameter expansion to remove the files that contain /cache/ and /tmp/ in their paths from the array.

This is what I have so far but it doesn't work. The problem seems to be that the second string replacement happens before the first one stores its result in first_array. So first_array has no value yet when the second replace executes resulting in second_array being blank. The goal is to get a list of files that have a timestamp from yesterday's date that don't contain /cache/ or /tmp/ in their paths.

```
#!/bin/bash

FIND="$(find . -type f -newermt $(date -d 'yesterday 13:00' '+%Y-%m-%d') ! -newermt $(date '+%Y-%m-%d'))"
readarray -t my_array <<<"$FIND"
first_array="${my_array[@]//*\/tmp\/*/}"
second_array="${first_array[@]//*\/cache\/*/}"
```

Comment: `FIND` , `first_array` and `second_array` does not have an array data structure, all of them are just a whole strings. Also `find` has an option to negate strings in the filename just like you negated the date/time.

Comment: Please paste your script there first: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: `-newermt $(date -d 'yesterday 13:00' '+%Y-%m-%d')` will just ignore the 13:00 time since the output format does not include hours and minutes.

Comment: @LéaGris Putting the middle of the day as the time guarantees that "yesterday" will always return yesterday's date. That's helpful if "yesterday" rolls the date back twenty-four hours because on midnight the day after daylight saving time begins, twenty-four hours ago is two days ago instead of one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filtering-out unwanted paths within `find`, and populating the array with `null` delimited output from find:

```sh
readarray -d '' -t my_array < <(
  find . -type f \
    -not \( \
      -path '*/tmp/*' -o -path '*/cache/*' \
    \) \
    -newermt "$(date -d 'yesterday 13:00' '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')" \
    -not -newermt "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')" \
    -print0
)
```

Answer (score 3):

`first_array` is not an array; it's a space-separated string. When assigning to `second_array`, if *any* of the original array elements had `tmp` or `cache`, the entire *string* is removed.

```
FIND="$(find . -type f -newermt $(date -d 'yesterday 13:00' '+%Y-%m-%d') ! -newermt $(date '+%Y-%m-%d'))"
readarray -t my_array <<<"$FIND"

# Use array assignment so that each element of my_array becomes a separate
# element of first_array
first_array=("${my_array[@]//*\/tmp\/*/}")

# Ditto for first_array -> second_array
second_array=("${first_array[@]//*\/cache\/*/}")
```

Comment: This doesn't quite do it. It converts the array entries containing "/tmp/" or "/cache/" to the empty string rather than deleting them. Depending on how the array's going to be used, this might or might not be sufficient.

Comment: I know. Now I need to filter out the empty values somehow.

Comment: I'd filter-out tmp and cache paths within find, and use null delimited entries from find to populate the array rather than store output of find in a string then split the string into an array with hazardous newline delimiter.

Comment: Indeed. Also, consider whether you need an array in the first place, and can't just use `-exec` to execute the command that would use the array.