# Replacing placeholder using SED

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have an use case, where i need to replace a placeholder using a string  having `[]` and a `$` and `-`  inside that.

example
`[- $the_real_ip]/@@log_pattern@@` .
i need to replace my `log pattern` using                           `[- $the_real_ip]` using `sed`. let me know if there is any option to do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escape a string for a sed replace pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern)

Comment: Also [Replace one substring for another string in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13210880/7665043). Top answer is a "Bashism" that doesn't use `sed`, if your script is meant to be Bash-only.

Comment: my intention is use sed for the replacement.

Comment: The top answer of the first link above is related to escaping special characters so they're not interpreted by the shell before sed is ran, and links to a much longer answer which is more like an article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see why just escaping them wouldn't work.

```
sed 's@\[\- \$the_real_ip\]@log_pattern@' file
```