# Replace string in variable using Bash

Tags: string, bash, variables, replace

I'd like to replace a string within a variable, e.g.:

```
Test=Today, 12:34
```

I'd like to replace the "Today" within the variable `Test` with a `Date` variable I declared before.

I tried using the `sed` command:

```
sed -i -e "s/Today/$Date" '$Test'
```

But it would just print out an error and the file `'$Test'` is not known. Is using `sed` only possible with text files?

Comment: `$Test` is not a file. You can use: `sed '....' <<< "$Test"` or better do it in bash itself using `"${Test/Today/$Date}"`

Comment: In addition to what @anubhava said, note that in bash, variable expansion will not work in single quotes. If you want to expand the Test variable, you can either leave it unquoted `$Test` or put it in double-quotes `"$Test"`. If you use single quotes it will be treated as a string literal.

Comment: When I write only the command "${Test/Today/$Date}", this doesn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace one substring for another string in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210880/replace-one-substring-for-another-string-in-shell-script)

Comment: `"${Test/Today/$Date}"` isn't a command, it's an expression that produces a string. You need to do something with that string, like set a variable to it (`Test="${Test/Today/$Date}"` would replace the current value of `Test` with the modified version), print it (`echo "${Test/Today/$Date}"`), or something like that.

Answer (score 13):

First, that's a syntax error.

```
$: Test=Today, 12:34
bash: 12:34: command not found
```

Put some quoting on it.

```
$: Test="Today, 12:34"
$: Test='Today, 12:34'
$: Test=Today,\ 12:34
```

Then you can just use `bash`'s built-in [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
$: Test='Today, 12:34'
$: Date=12.12.2000
$: Test="${Test/Today/$Date}"
$: echo "$Test"
12.12.2000, 12:34
```

Answer (score 8):

This works for me:

```
Test="Today, 12:34"
Date=12.12.2000
sed 's/Today/'"$Date"'/g' <<<"$Test"
```

Edit: If you would like to change the variable Test, like mentioned in the comment, you need the assignment:

```
Test="Today, 12:34"
Date=12.12.2000
Test=$(sed 's/Today/'"$Date"'/g' <<<"$Test")
```

Answer (score 5):

To do this you don't need to make any use of `sed` and can, instead, make use of the little-known, but extremely handy feature of Bash called [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) described [here](https://linuxhandbook.com/replace-string-bash/). I only know about this because it came up in a job interview once and the interviewer shared it with me then left me to clean my brains up off the floor...

```bash
Test='Today, 12:34'
Date='12.12.2000'
echo "${Test/Today/$Date}"
---
12.12.2000, 12:34
```

As I said, this blew my mind in that job interview. I didn't get the job, but I've used this feature just about every day since.

Comment: Parameter expansion is quite useful for changing file endings: `for f in *.pdf; do echo "${f/%.pdf/.test}"; done`. This will print each file name with the last occurrence of ".pdf" changed to ".test".