# Space in directory name (git bash)

Tags: windows, bash, git-bash

I have Windows operating system. I am using GIT BASH. I have written script `run.sh` and run it in this way:

```
$ ./run.sh
```

---

This code works correctly:

```
dir="/c/Windows"
app="notepad.exe"
$dir/$app
```

application notepad will open as a result.

---

But I can't run the following code:

```
dir="/c/Program Files/7-Zip"
app="7zFM.exe"
$dir/$app
```

as a result a get an error message:

```
./run.sh: line 63: /c/Program: No such file or directory
```

---

I try this:

```
dir='/c/"Program Files"/7-Zip'
app="7zFM.exe"
$dir/$app
```

as a result:

```
./run.sh: line 63: /c/"Program: No such file or directory
```

---

Then i try this:

```
dir=/c/Program\ Files/7-Zip
app="7zFM.exe"
$dir/$app
```

also error:

```
./run.sh: line 63: /c/Program: No such file or directory
```

---

How can i use **space in directory name** in GIT BASH ?

Comment: Quote `"$dir"` to prevent word splitting.  See: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Answer (score 0):

Unrelated question, but the answer is to the point - c.f. [Replace String in variable using bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63707634/replace-string-in-variable-using-bash/63709992#63709992)

Short answer - always quote your variables unless you know WHY you shouldn't in a specific circumstance.

```
$dir/$app       # doesn't work: /c/Program: No such file or directory
"$dir/$app"     # works fine
"$dir"/"$app"   # works fine
```

You can also combine them.

```
p="$dir/$app"   # assignment works
$p              # doesn't work: /c/Program: No such file or directory
"$p"            # works fine.
```

You have to protect the embedded space when it's being *used.*