# Find and replace string in command line args in bash

Tags: bash

I have bash script which takes set of command line argument. Now I want to remove some of the argument that I received from user and pass it to other script. How can I achieve this.

remove_arts.sh

```bash
echo "Prints all args passed $*"
# Add logic to remove args value --native/-nv/--cross
my_app_args=$(command to store result in $*)
bash run_my_app.sh my_app_args
```

So when I run that script with

```
bash remove_arts.sh --native -nv --execute_rythm
```

After processing `bash run_my_app.sh --execute_rythm`

I have checked [Replace one substring for another string in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210880/replace-one-substring-for-another-string-in-shell-script)
which suggested to use

```
first=${first//Suzy/$second}
```

But I am not able to use `$second` as empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each argument, store all arguments that are not in the list of excludes inside an array. Then pass that array to your script.

```
# Add logic to remove args value --native/-nv/--cross
args=()
for i in "$@"; do
  case "$i" in
  --native|-nv|--cross) ;;
  *) args+=("$i"); ;;
  esac
done
run_my_app.sh "${args[@]}"
```

You might want to research bash arrays and read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 . Remember to check your scripts with shellcheck

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This will work for me. I was wondering is there any way we can optimize this code. find and replace similar to python. `$*.replace('--native', '')`.

Comment: The code should be quite fast - it's only bash with no subprocesses. I do not think there's anything to optimize.

Comment: ok Thanks. By optimize I mean we can reduce number of line. Though this works as expected :).

Comment: You can put the whole script on one single line, if you wish (separate commands with `;` or `&&`).