# How to replace the substring or first N characters using shell script?

Tags: macos, shell

I ned to replace the substring from shell script.
Using bellow link i have try but no luck.

[Replace one substring for another string in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210880/replace-one-substring-for-another-string-in-shell-script)

I have try:

```
variableString=$(find . -type f -name 'test.*.nupkg')
oldstr="./"
newstr=""
result=$(echo $variableString | sed "s/$oldstr/$newstr/g")
echo "Original String :  $variableString"
echo "Replaced String :  $result"
```

output:

```
Original String :  ./test.6.0.19.nupkg
Replaced String :
```

I need to replace the `./` to ""

Excepted output:

```
Original String :  ./test.6.0.19.nupkg
Replaced String :  test.6.0.19.nupkg
```

Comment: The program you posted does **not** produce the output you claimed, but yields an error message. If you run your program with `set -x` turned on, you will see that the sed command expands to `sed s/.///g`, and this is of course incorrect (just count the slashes!).

Answer (score 0):

I am able to replace the first two character.

```
variableString=$(find . -type f -name 'test.*.nupkg')
result=${variableString:2}
echo "Original String :  $variableString"
echo "Replaced String :  $result"
```

output

```
Original String :  ./test.6.0.19.nupkg
Replaced String :  test.6.0.19.nupkg
```

thx