# Linux matching start and end and replace

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a file which contains only one line but it is really really long.
I would like to get specific part from the line and replace to something else.

Hereunder an example test :

```
This is an exemple text should be very long long text in my real case i am trying to find something like start/end with to replace to something else.
```

I am imagining like ->  start with **"exemple text"** end with **"real case"**

Expected result : **"exemple text should be very long long text in my real case"**

to replace  :  empty

Could you please help me ?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210880/replace-one-substring-for-another-string-in-shell-script

Answer (score 0):

Look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210880/replace-one-substring-for-another-string-in-shell-script) up,
assuming you use bash:

```bash
myString="This is an exemple text should be very long long text in my real case i am trying to find something like start/end with to replace to something else."
echo "${myString/"This is an exemple text should be very long long text in my real case i am trying to find something like start/end with to replace to something else."/"exemple text should be very long long text in my real case"}"
```

Comment: the thing is the block which i want to replace has more than 200 characters.... this is why i am trying to find some kind of "start" to precise first and last word of this block..